Leaving (sweet) peppers on the vine?
Our season has been unusually long this year, with still no frost forecast.  (I think we're now Zone 6.)  We have a lot of 'Sweet Italian' peppers, which are fully red. The leaves are still green.
My question is, what would be the effect of leaving the peppers on the vine?  Is there some point of 'peak sweetness', after which flavor degrades?  (For instance, maybe sugars start converting to starches, and/or older leaves stop producing sugars.)

Aren't you frost-free until at least Halloween? As the fruit starts drying and shrinking, wouldn't it become sweeter for eating and roasting?

Yosef: Frost isn't the concern.  But, if you're saying that they get sweeter right through frost, despite loss of sunlight and leaf 'aging'/deterioration, then I guess that would be the answer.  Do you know this to be so?

What do I know? The gardener plans and nature improvises.

As most of fruits: after some time they may start to rot. Just look (mainly on top). Note: cold can also change some flavours (better or worse: i do not know, but it is something general)
